# Deleting last whitespace in Array - java

Tags: java, arrays

my program has to print words backward with upper cases and at the end of every line print a dot. Can you please help me with deleting the last whitespace before the dot?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int pocet = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < pocet; i++) {
        String veta = sc.nextLine();
        String veta2=veta.replaceAll("\\s+"," ");
        String[] words = veta2.split(" "); 
        String result = "";
        for (int j = 0; j<words.length;j++){
            for (int k = words[j].length(); k > 0; k--) {
            result = result + words[j].substring(k - 1, k);

            }
        words[j] = result;
        result = "";
        //return result.replaceAll("\\s+$", "");
        }

        words[words.length-1]= words[words.length-1];

        System.out.println();

    for (int j =0; j<words.length; j++){
        char whitespace = ' ';
         System.out.print(words[j].toUpperCase()+whitespace);
     }
    }
    System.out.print(".");
    System.out.println();

  }    
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is not working, resp. what is your question?

Comment: Add a test scenario with the results, and indicate the expected result.

Comment: You don't even need to do that yourself since java 8 with [String.join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-). Please provide a [mcve] for better answers.

Comment: Why `words[words.length-1]= words[words.length-1];`, you are doing `a = a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your for by the code below:

```
for (int j =0; j<words.length; j++){
     char whitespace = ' ';
     System.out.print(words[j].toUpperCase());
     if (j < (words.length - 1)) {
         System.out.print(whitespace);
    }
}
```

That way, you will add a whitespace except for the last word of your array

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) to concatenate every `String` separated by the `CharSequence` you want (here a space) instead of that for loop.

```
String wordString = String.join(" ", words);
```

There, you won't need to remove anything. You still need to do an uppercase on the result before printing it.

```
wordString = wordString.toUpperCase()
System.out.println(wordString);
```

Answer (score 0):

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner  in    = new Scanner(System.in);

```
    System.out.printf("Please insert number of lines you want to enter: ");        
    String[] input = new String[in.nextInt()];
    in.nextLine(); 

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        input[i] = in.nextLine();
    }
    String output = null;
   for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++) {
       output="";
       String[] lst = new String[input[i].split(" ").length];
       lst = input[i].split(" ");

        for(int j = lst.length-1; j >= 0; j--) {

            output+=(j==0)?lst[j]+".":lst[j]+" ";
        }
        System.out.println(output);
   }

}
```